# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Landroid/view/SurfaceView;II)V

Tags: java, android, agora.io

I am facing this issue in my agora sdk while opening live cameraview .I Added agora sdk module in my project and there is already agora implemented in the main module. So please suggest me is this is the duplicate library issue or library version issue . I searched everywhere but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented Agora SDK using "implementation 'io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:x.y.z" in the build.gradle file, you don't need to add the Agora SDK manually.

You can check this demo code for reference: https://github.com/AgoraIO/Basic-Video-Call/tree/master/One-to-One-Video/Agora-Android-Tutorial-1to1

And here is a guide about how to run this demo: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/run_demo_video_call_android?platform=Android